# how to open file in another pane in Tmux

Tags: bash, tmux, terminator

I'm new to tmux, and split a window into 3 panes, left half(main pane), top-right quarter and bottom-right quarter. Is it possible that I use command to open an editable file in the left main pane, say `vim myFile.py`, and myFile.py will open in another pane, say top-right pane, such that I can always edit file in the top-right pane and keep input commands int eh left main pane?

Comment: So you want to type `vim myFile.py` in the top-left pane, but actually open `vim` in the top-right pane, leaving the shell running in the top-left pane?

Comment: yes, but it seems impossible...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible to do using features of vim, but it has nothing to do with tmux specifically. If the version of vim you are using was compiled with the `+clientserver` option, then there is a way to do this. To check, run `:version` in vim, and look for `+clientserver`. The client server capabilities of vim depend on X11, so if you don't see it, installing gvim might help. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23601 for more information on the X11 dependency.

Now on to how to use it. First, set up your tmux panes however you want. In the pane that you would like to be the dedicated editor, the following command will create a vim "server."

```
vim --servername tmuxEditor
```

Now from another pane, you can run

```
vim --servername tmuxEditor --remote files...
```

and the editor will open the specified file(s). Other useful commands are

```
vim --servername tmuxEditor --remote-tab files...
vim --servername tmuxEditor --remote-send keys
```

The first opens the specified file(s) in separate tabs, and the second sends the specified key sequence to the server.

See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html or run `:help remote` in vim for more information on vim's client server features.

Comment: Very nice. I'll just add that whatever command is used to create the pane where the vim server will run can also start `vim` as the initial process, rather than the default shell.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to open file at existing Vim instance (if it is running inside tmux session):

```
tmux send-keys -t vim:1.0 Escape ":tabnew path/to/your_file.txt" C-m
```

where `vim:1.0` is pane selector (`vim` - session name, `1` - index of window, `0` - index of pane).

Comment: How can you switch focus to the pane with the opened file?

Comment: @mroavi You need something like this: `tmux select-window -t vim:1.0 \; select-pane -t vim:1.0`. You can skip `select-window` if you have single window.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: you can use `tmux` to open commands in panes other than the current pane, but dpk2442's solution using `vim`'s client/server features is probably cleaner.

---

One option is to set `remain-on-exit` option on the top-right pane, then use the `respawn-pane` command to start `vim` in the pane.

Say the pane identifier of the top-right pane is `0:0.1` (session 0, window 0, pane 1; you'll need to adjust this for your setup). You can set the `remain-on-exit` option using

```
tmux set-option -t 0:0 remain-on-exit on
```

(This sets the option for any pane in the window, not just one particular pane.)

Then, use

```
tmux respawn-command -k -t 0:0.1 vim myFile.py
```

to open `vim` in the pane specified by the argument to the `-t` option. `-`k` ensures that any command already running in the pane is killed; you can omit it if you know that nothing is currently running in that pane.

Give the length of the command, you'll probably want to define a shell function to launch `vim` in the desired pane:

```
start_vim () {
    tmux respawn-command -k -t 0:0.1 vim "$1"
}
```

so you can just run

```
start_vim myFile.py
```